# Find the area of a polygon

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

Given consecutive side lengths `s1, s2, s3... s_n` of an n-gon inscribed in a circle, find its area. You may assume that the polygon exists. In addition, the polygon will be convex and not self-intersecting, which is enough to guarantee uniqueness. Built-ins that specifically solve this challenge, as well as built-in functions that calculate the circumradius or circumcenter, are banned (this is different from a previous version of this challenge).

Input: The side lengths of the cyclic polygon; may be taken as parameters to a function, stdin, etc.

Output: The area of the polygon.

The answer should be accurate to 6 decimal places and must run within 20 seconds on a reasonable laptop.

This is code golf so shortest code wins!

Specific test cases:

```
[3, 4, 5] --> 6
[3, 4, 6] --> 5.332682251925386
[3, 4, 6, 7] --> 22.44994432064365
[5, 5, 5, 5] --> 25
[6, 6, 6, 6, 6] --> 61.93718642120281
[6.974973020933265, 2.2393294197257387, 5.158285083300981, 1.4845682771595603, 3.5957940796134173] --> 21.958390804292847
[7.353566082457831, 12.271766915518073, 8.453884922273897, 9.879017670784675, 9.493366404245332, 1.2050010402321778] --> 162.27641678140589
```

Test case generator:

```js
function randPolygon(n) {
  var left = 2 * Math.PI;
  var angles = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    var r = Math.random() * left;
    angles.push(r);
    left -= r;
  }
  angles.push(left);
  var area = 0;
  var radius = 1 + Math.random() * 9;
  for (var i = 0; i < angles.length; ++i) area += radius * radius * Math.sin(angles[i]) / 2;
  var sideLens = angles.map(function(a) {
    return Math.sin(a / 2) * radius * 2;
  });

  document.querySelector("#radius").innerHTML = radius;
  document.querySelector("#angles").innerHTML = "[" + angles.join(", ") + "]";
  document.querySelector("#inp").innerHTML = "[" + sideLens.join(", ") + "]";
  document.querySelector("#out").innerHTML = area;

  draw(angles);
}

function draw(angles) {
  var canv = document.querySelector("#diagram"),
    ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
  var size = canv.width
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size, size);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(size / 2, size / 2, size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(size, size / 2);
  var runningTotal = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < angles.length; ++i) {
    runningTotal += angles[i];
    var x = Math.cos(runningTotal) * size / 2 + size / 2;
    var y = Math.sin(runningTotal) * size / 2 + size / 2;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
document.querySelector("#gen").onclick = function() {
  randPolygon(parseInt(document.querySelector("#sideLens").value, 10));
}
```

```html
<div id="hints">
  <p><strong>These are to help you; they are not part of the input or output.</strong>
  </p>
  Circumradius:
  <pre id="radius"></pre>
  Angles, in radians, of each sector (this are NOT the angles of the polygon):
  <pre id="angles"></pre>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="output">
  Input:
  <pre id="inp"></pre>
  Output:
  <pre id="out"></pre>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="draw">
  Diagram:
  <br />
  <canvas id="diagram" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
</div>

Number of side lengths:
<input type="number" id="sideLens" step="1" min="3" value="3" />
<br />
<button id="gen">Generate test case</button>
```

Comment: I know an easy way to find its perimeter.

Comment: I know an easy way to find the number of sides

Comment: This problem is pretty easy given the circumradius, but without it it's incredibly difficult.

Comment: It's also easy if there are fewer than five sides, not that it matters in code golf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Python 2, <s>195</s> 191 bytes

```python
from math import*
C=sorted(input());l,h=0,1/max(C)
while h-l>2e-16:m=(l+h)/2;a=[asin(c*m)for c in C[:-1]];f=pi-sum(a);l,h=[l,m,h][sin(f)/m>C[-1]:][:2]
print sum(sin(2*t)/l/l for t in a+[f])/8
```

Uses a binary search to find the inverse diameter, then calculates the area of each segment by the angle/radius.

It finds the radius by first summing all but the largest chord angle, and checking the remaining angle to the remaining chord. Those angles are then also used to compute the area of each segment. A segment's area can be negative, if it's angle is bigger than 180 degrees. We do a binary search over the inverse diameter so the domain is bounded and well-behaved.

Readable implementation:

```python
def segment_angles(line_segments, invd):
    return [2*math.asin(c*invd) for c in line_segments]

def cyclic_ngon_area(line_segments):
    line_segments = list(sorted(line_segments))
    lo, hi = 0, 1/max(line_segments)
    while hi - lo > 2e-16:
        mid = (lo + hi) / 2
        angles = segment_angles(line_segments[:-1], mid)
        angles.append(2*math.pi - sum(angles))
        if math.sin(angles[-1]/2) / mid > line_segments[-1]:
            lo = mid
        else:
            hi = mid
    return sum([math.sin(a)/lo/lo/8 for a in angles])
```

Comment: Does this work if the center is outside the polygon? (For example, a triangle with side lengths 6, 7, 12). Sometimes the `sqrt(4**2 - c**2/4)` needs to be negative, when the angle is greater than `pi`.

Comment: @soktinpk I fixed my answer.

Comment: The code gives wrong results for the input [1000000, 1000000, 1999999]. The exact result for this test is 1999999*sqrt(3999999)/4 = 999999375.0000546875...

Comment: @HugoPfoertner I fixed it by squaring the initial `hi` estimate, at the cost of 3 bytes.

Comment: Squaring the perimeter does not eliminate the problem that arises in polygon degeneracy when the longest side approaches the sum of the smaller sides. Then the radius can be arbitrarily large. I have now described this in more detail in the explanation of my program. Try the example [0.25, 0.25, 0.499999]. Your program returns 0.0077512398... instead of the correct result ~= 0.000125. Test cases using Mathematica: Table [ResourceFunction["HeronFormula"][{1/4,1/4,1/2-1/10^n}]+0.,{n,1,9} ] -> {0.03, 0.0121886, 0.00394297, 0.00124969, 0.000395275, 0.000125, 0.0000395285, 0.0000125,3.95285*10^-6}

Comment: @HugoPfoertner Right, it's unbounded. I fixed my answer by instead doing a binary search over the inverse diameter, which lies in `(0, 1/max(edges)]`. There's still numerical precision loss, but it should give 6 significant digits of precision for reasonable-sized inputs.

Comment: @orlp: It's okay now; the specification of the OP is potentially ambiguous with "accurate to 6 decimal places". He probably had "6 significant digits" in mind. I suspect that he overlooked the possibility of degeneracy, otherwise the test examples would have included one or two with this property.

Answer (score 5):

## PARI/GP, 182 bytes

```
A(v)=n=#s=vecsort(v);g=1^s;h=sum(k=1,n-1,asin(s[k]/S=s[n]))<Pi/2;g[n]-=2*h;d=solve(D=S,S/(vecsum(s)/2/S-1),sum(k=1,n,g[k]*asin(s[k]/D))-Pi*!h);sum(k=1,n,g[k]*s[k]*sqrt(d^2-s[k]^2))/4
```

Using @alephalpha's hints that global variables can be used and his improved chained assignments, significantly shorter code is possible. Also an unnecessary factor 8 in calculation of Dmax was removed.

### Version with comments

```
AreaCyclicPolygon(VectorofSidelenghts) =
{
  my( s = vecsort(VectorofSidelenghts), \\ allows access to longest side
                                        \\ and loop over shorter sides
      n = #s,
      S = s[n],    \\ assignment postponed into loop in golfed code
      g = vector(n,i,1), \\ Auxiliary vector of ones
      d,
      h = sum ( k=1, n-1, asin(s[k]/S)) < Pi/2, \\ determine whether the triangle 
                                                   \\ with longest side makes an angle > Pi.
      Dmax = S/sqrt(vecsum(s)/2/S - 1) \\ upper limit of diameter from asymptotic
                                             \\ expansion showing 1/sqrt(eps) dependency.
                                             \\ In "golfed" version sqrt can be ommitted
                                             \\ drastically overestimating Dmax; solve still works
    );
  g[n] -= 2*h; \\ factor = -1 for largest triangle
               \\ when the polygon only occupies less than half of the circle
  d = solve ( D=s[n], Dmax,
              sum (k=1, n, g[k]*asin(s[k]/D)) - Pi*!h); \\ solve sum of angles equation
                                                        \\ including special case of
                                                        \\ large angle for longest side
  sum (k=1, n, g[k]*s[k]*sqrt(d^2 - s[k]^2))/4  \\ return value: use solution for d in sum
                                                \\ of triangle areas, again with potentially
                                                \\ negative contribution of triangle
                                                \\ with longest side
};
```

### Examples

```
AreaCyclicPolygon([3,4,5])
 6.000000000000000000
AreaCyclicPolygon([3,4,6])
 5.3326822519253854377215978803358864040
AreaCyclicPolygon([0.25,0.25,0.499999])
 0.00012499968750010937502343751074219391159
AreaCyclicPolygon([5,5,5,5])
 25.000000000000000000000000000000000000
AreaCyclicPolygon([6,6,6,6,6])
 61.937186421202809219324431185989945578
AreaCyclicPolygon([1e6,1e6,2e6-1])
 999999375.00005468750292968783569307190
```

### Note on estimating the maximum diameter

Regardless of whether the diameter (or equivalently the radius) is calculated using bisection or with a function for solving a non-linear equation (like PARI's solve here), a bracketing interval is required for the solution value. Trivially, the diameter cannot be smaller than the longest side. However, since the polygon can degenerate when the sum of the shorter sides approaches the longest side, the diameter of the polygon can become arbitrarily large. In order to estimate this diameter, it is sufficient to use a triangle as a model. From the well-known Heron formula for the area A one gets the radius
$$
r(a,b,c) = \frac{a b c}{\sqrt{(a+b-c) (a-b+c) (-a+b+c) (a+b+c)}}
$$
If one assumes a model triangle \$\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon \right)\$ normalized to an approximate perimeter of 1 with a scaled length deficit \$\epsilon\$ of the longest side, then r becomes
$$
r = \frac{\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon }{16 \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon \right)^2 (1-\epsilon ) \epsilon }}
$$
Assuming \$\epsilon\$ to be small, r can be expanded r in a series
$$
r = \frac{1}{16 \sqrt{\epsilon }}+\frac{\sqrt{\epsilon }}{32}+\frac{3 \epsilon ^{3/2}}{128}+O\left(\epsilon ^{5/2}\right)
$$
The leading term contains the singularity \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}\$, which must be taken into account when calculating the upper bound. It doesn't matter whether you use the circumference or the longest side to scale back.

Whether one computes \$\epsilon\$ as
$$
\epsilon = \frac{a+b+c}{2 c}-1 = \frac{a+b-c}{2 c}
$$
which is the **vecsum(s)/2/S - 1** in the program, or as
$$
\epsilon = 1-\frac{2 c}{a+b+c}
$$
makes no essential difference for small \$\epsilon\$.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I'm really happy to see a new PARI/GP answer. 
Using global variables is fine in code golf. So you don't need to use `my`. `my(s=vecsort(v),n=#v,S=s[n],g=vector(n,i,1),d,h=sum(k=1,n-1,asin(s[k]/S))<Pi/2)` can become `S=s[n=#s=vecsort(v)];g=1^s;h=sum(k=1,n-1,asin(s[k]/S))<Pi/2`.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I don't know enough about the rules here. May I incorporate your suggestions into my code? As an editor in OEIS, I constantly look at PARI code and occasionally create code myself. But there we often have the opposite problem, that we criticize poorly readable code. But it's fun here and I plan to contribute from time to time.

Comment: Since my reputation is not yet high enough to make comments on other posts, I'll say this at this point: @orlp 's Python code returns an incorrect result with the input of my last test example, because the starting value for the upper bound "hi" is set much too low for this input. print (cyclic_ngon_area ([1000000, 1000000, 1999999])) -> 124019623218.91309. Setting the hi value correctly is more laborious and requires longer code.

Comment: @HugoPfoertner Sorry. When I said you can use global variables, I meant that you can use global variables in functions (instead of local variables declared by `my`), not that you can assume the input is stored in a global variable. You should still define a function that takes the input.

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, 89 bytes

```
r=sum(s=input(''));while sum(a=asin(s/2/r))<pi r*=1-1e-4;b=a;end;disp(sum(cos(b).*s/2*r))
```

### Explanation

The angle `a` spanned by a segment of length `s` is `2*asin(s/2/r)`, given a circumradius `r`. Its area is `cos(a)*s/2*r`.

#### Algorithm

1. Set `r` to something too large, such as the perimeter.
2. If the cumulated angle is smaller than `2pi`, reduce `r` and repeat step 2.
3. Calculate the area.

Comment: On average, how many iterations does this take for `r` to be set? (out of curiosity)

Comment: There is no way this has the required precision. You repeatedly multiply the radius by 0.9999 to reduce it, this makes it very easy to undershoot the required 6 decimals of precision.

Comment: @soktinpk around 15000 for `r*=1-1e-4` and 150000 for `r*=1-1e-5`.

Comment: @RainerP. Those two values are the same.

Comment: @orlp you can increase precision by increasing the exponent in `r*=1-1e-4` at the cost of run time.

Comment: This answer is not correct when the centre is outside the polygon, unless octave has a magical `asin`. After testing it online, it returns a complex answer for `[6, 7, 12]`.

Comment: I'll let you keep this answer since you already posted it, but future answers must meet the required precision within 20 seconds, and this answer requires `1e-4` to be at least `1e-7`, and then takes about 2 minutes to find an answer. Sorry, the question should have been clearer.

Comment: @orlp You are right, it's broken. I'll have to fix it.

Comment: @soktinpk it is generally not a good idea to make an exception for a specific answer.

Comment: @Cyoce But I don't want to make him/her delete it since it wasn't originally specified in the challenge. I'll let the answer stay up, but it won't be part of the "competition" and can't be accepted. (Rainer P. can also probably delete it himself if he wants since it may not gather many upvotes anyway).